# Materialboxed Doesn't work in ie and mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

http://webtehayat.net/demo/portfolio/
Materialboxed Doesn't work in ie and mobile.
Help please.

Comment: Looks ok to me on ie11. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: Thank you, please check in the phone

Comment: i need help please

Comment: Sorry I don't have a phone with IE

Comment: You can also look at chrome on the phone.

Comment: Help pls this is important